# Monitor kubernetes ingress resources with elastic heartbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-beats

Is there any way to configure elastic heartbeat to automatically detect the ingress resources in a cluster and run a simple health-check against each of them ?

Otherwise, what would be a simple alternative to that ?
Like an operator that subscribes to Ingress resources events and for each of the active Ingress resources run a GET on a preconfigured health-check endpoint.

Comment: ingress controller such as nginx plus already does active health check on backend services...why do you want to do healthcheck separately?

Comment: So I want basic monitoring + email alerting on Ingress endpoints. The ones that are actually consumed by end users. I'm already using elastic for log aggregation and grafana for monitoring. Grafana already supports elastic as a datasource and has an alerting engine. If you can suggest a better approach, please do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on the current [heartbeat (actually common for all beats) codebase](https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/libbeat/autodiscover/providers/kubernetes/kubernetes.go#L104), I assume there is not.

```
    switch config.Resource {
case "pod":
    p.eventer, err = NewPodEventer(uuid, c, client, p.publish)
case "node":
    p.eventer, err = NewNodeEventer(uuid, c, client, p.publish)
case "service":
    p.eventer, err = NewServiceEventer(uuid, c, client, p.publish)
default:
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("unsupported autodiscover resource %s", config.Resource)
}
```